# SharePoint Online Search: Filter by FileType

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I have some custom webpart that uses the SharePoint Online Search. By `$select`ing the managed property `FileType/FileExtension`, I can see the extension of the search results:

[image]

(screenshot from Search Query Tool)

If a have two PowerPoint files, one has .pptx and one .ppt file extension, these are two different values in the refiners. So, I cannot search for "All PowerPoint files".

Is there any way to reach this goal?

BR